# get server roles and features powershell including version

Tags: powershell

I need a PS command that can get me all the role and features installed on a Server2016.

`Get-WindowsFeature` does help me, but I need the version number as well.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Version of what?  The OS and update level?

Answer (score 3):

[`Get-WindowsFeature`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servermanager/get-windowsfeature) contains the version information in the attribute `AdditionalInfo`:

```
Get-WindowsFeature |Where Installed |
  Select name,@{name='Version';expression={"{0}.{1}" -f $_.AdditionalInfo.MajorVersion,$_.AdditionalInfo.MinorVersion }}
```

Sample output:

```
Name                    Version
----                    -------
NET-Framework-Features  3.5
User-Interfaces-Infra   8.0
Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra   8.0
Server-Gui-Shell        8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for *[Get-ComputerInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo?view=powershell-6)* ?
this will tell you OS edition, version, build, hotfix, roles, etc.